# Passing variables down Mocha test suites

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I am creating a connection (and cleaning up a database) with mongoose before running all tests with mocha like so (_setup.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.env().argv(); 

var _conn;

before(function(done){
    _conn = mongoose.createConnection(nconf.get('TEST_DB'), function(error){
      if(error) return done(error);

      _conn.db.dropDatabase(done);
   });
});

after(function(done){
   _conn.db.dropDatabase(function(error){
       if(error) return done(error);

       _conn.close(done);
   });
});
```

Other test suites need this connection to build the mongoose models. I am using a separate connection instead of the default mongoose connection because these tests can be run in app through the mocha js api. The app uses the default mongoose connection. Example test needing connection variable:

```
var should = require('should'),
service = require('../lib/service')(_conn); // << somehow need that conn variable created in before tests

describe('Service', function(){

   describe('#dodboperation()', function(){

       //tests and stuff
```

Is there anyway to pass variables between files/test suites in mocha? Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use environment variables. At the top of your mocha file, include:

```
process.env.TEST = 'true'; // Use test database
```

Then, include use a database config like this one:

```
var url = require('url');
var config = {};
var dbUrl;

if (typeof(process.env.DATABASE_URL) !== 'undefined') {
    dbUrl = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
}
else if (process.env.TEST === 'true') {
    dbUrl = url.parse('tcp://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/test');
}
else {
    dbUrl = url.parse('tcp://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/db');
}

config.dialect = 'postgres';
config.protocol = dbUrl.protocol.substr(0, dbUrl.protocol.length - 1); // Remove trailing ':'
config.username = dbUrl.auth.split(':')[0];
config.password = dbUrl.auth.split(':')[1];
config.host = dbUrl.hostname;
config.port = dbUrl.port;
config.database = dbUrl.path.substring(1);

console.log('Using database ' + config.database);
module.exports = config;
```

We also run two different servers on different ports on our dev machines. We run nodemon on port 4000 for regular development, and then if TEST == 'true' the server runs on port 4500.

Comment: it works well for variables, i was looking for doing the same with objects , anything we could use as the environment variables seem to strip down the objects to a single line text

Comment: Environment variables can only hold strings. You could encode your object as JSON and put it in the environment variable, or you could store the JSON somewhere like in a temp file.

Comment: but that object will not be the 'same' object that was initialized, we will get a copy of it or the fields in it, eg, if the original object changes, my env json won't. There should be an alternative. Im using mocha with sails which supports global variables so im piggy-backing my variables over sails (using sails.config.var), I was looking for something that mocha could support out of the box when im not using something like sails for example.

Comment: finally found a solution which works the way it should, mocha supports global variables, need to provide them in command line switch and then access anywhere. (mocha --globals var1,var2... testfile.js)